# How to refresh DataTables sort and filter info

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatable, filtering

For simplicity of the example I have a DataTable which I load from HTML.

This DataTable is having parts of its content updated through jQuery BUT the updated content while visible in the table, does not reflect when sorting or filtering.

See html code below

```
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Votes</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>John</th>
      <th>Doe</th>
      <th id="entry1_votes">50</th>
      <th>London</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Hill</th>
      <th>Vaught</th>
      <th id="entry2_votes">120</th>
      <th>Berlin</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Charles</th>
      <th>Roy</th>
      <th id="entry3_votes">78</th>
      <th>Liege</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').DataTable({});

  $("#entry2_votes").text(60);
});
```

So if you try sorting **Votes** column or try filtering by the new value **60** set through jQuery it wont work

See this working example https://jsfiddle.net/bpali/d97bpqvs/3/

Obviously, my question is how to make it work as in my real life situation I have to update parts of the DataTable constantly through different Ajax requests of different page sections and I cannot just put an ajax source on the table and reload the table.

Comment: you should try changing the table's data using [datatables API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data())

Comment: @Sebastianb thanks for you comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dt = $('#example').DataTable({});
  dt.cell( $("#entry2_votes") ).data(60) ;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Votes</th>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>John</th>
      <th>Doe</th>
      <th id="entry1_votes">50</th>
      <th>London</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Hill</th>
      <th>Vaught</th>
      <th id="entry2_votes">120</th>
      <th>Berlin</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Charles</th>
      <th>Roy</th>
      <th id="entry3_votes">78</th>
      <th>Liege</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/HappyiPhone/d97bpqvs/7/

Answer (score -1):

[Check online demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6j4msstb/)

You have to reinitialize data table after updating with jquery or you can update by datatable in-built methods/api

```
  $('#example').DataTable().destroy();
  $('#example').DataTable().draw();
```